# Pseudocode for calling 3 task (different time) at least once in the specified timing

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

There are 3 functions :
**func1** is  called every 200 usec, **func2** is called every 400 usec and **func3** is called every 800 usec.
The maximum execution time of each task is 100 us.
How to schedule the functions so that every task is executed?
Could 3 threads and 3 memory blocks ( for their operations) solve the process?
I am naive, so please bear it with me and this is my first post, so please accept my apologies for any mistake.

Comment: Assuming that each task takes no more than 100usec, you can [schedule them sequentially in a single thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufeFh.png).

Answer (score 1):

The maximum execution time should be less than 100usec because you will need some time for the scheduler and might have be able to handle some jitter.

For this fixed requirement of execution cycles and execution times you could use a single thread/task and reserve one slot of 100usec for `func1` and one slot for either `func2` or `func3` as necessary. To avoid exceeding the cycle time of 200usec with the sum of execution times you should avoid calling all 3 functions in the same cycle.

You could use a fixed scheduling in time slots of 100usec:

```
slot  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ...
func  1  2  1  3  1  2  1  _  1  2  1  3  1  2  1  _ ...
```

The numbers in the `func` row mean calling the respective function, underscore means calling no function in this time slot.

Assuming you have a scheduler function that is called every 100 usec, you could use a time slot counter that counts from 0 to 7 and restarts from 0 and a `switch`/`case`.

Example

```
// assumed to be called every 100usec
void scheduler(void)
{
    static int slot = 0;

    switch(slot)
    {
    case 0:
    case 2:
    case 4:
    case 6:
        func1(); // to be called every 200usec
        break;
    case 1:
    case 5:
        func2(); // to be called every 400usec
        break;
    case 3:
        func3() // to be called every 800usec
        break;
    case 7: // only for clarity, could be omitted
        // nothing, empty time slot
    }

    slot++;
    if(slot > 7)
    {
        slot = 0;
    }
}
```